# Looking for a Drupal 7 extension for cataloging PDF downloads

Tags: drupal

I am looking for a Drupal 7 extension for displaying a lot of PDF documents in a fashionable way. Preferably with search option to search through the pdf documents that are in a particular folder. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no need for an extension.

- design and create a **PDF Document** content type [admin/structure/types/add]
- create a view with exposed filters [admin/structure/views/add]

Easy as that.

You can naturally improve your catalogue with:

- A library to extract meta info from PDF docs [ example : http://www.pdfparser.org/], for a faster creation of nodes [node/add]
- Some CSS styling